# Re-setting all option buttons at once

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have written a code for re-setting all option button on one click but its giving an error, "object doesnt support the property or matter".

```
Sub Add_New_Record()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 30
    With Sheets("Form")
        '-- unlock the worksheet
        .Unprotect
        .OptionButton(i).Value = False

        '-- lock the worksheet
        '.Protect

        .Activate
        .Range("Q12").Select
     End With
     Next i
End Sub
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to fix the code and make the value of all option buttons "false" at one.

I know how to do it individually like:

```
Sub Add_New_Record()
    With Sheets("Form")
        '-- unlock the worksheet
        .Unprotect
        .OptionButton1.Value = False

        '-- lock the worksheet
        '.Protect
        .Activate
        .Range("Q12").Select
     End With
End Sub
```

but since I have too many buttons, the code will get really long and inefficient.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the OLEObjects on a  particular sheet and if it is an optionbutton then set it to false.

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Object) = "OptionButton" Then
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Object = False
    End If
Next i
```

Embedding this snippet in your code:

```
Sub Add_New_Record()
    With Sheets(1)
        .Unprotect
        For i = 1 To .OLEObjects.Count
            If TypeName(.OLEObjects(i).Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                .OLEObjects(i).Object = False
            End If
        Next i
        .Protect
        .Range("Q12").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Read more about OLEObjects [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178183(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First, the `With` statement should be before the `For` loop. And it should be `.OptionButtons`. Try this one.

```
Sub Add_New_Record()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Form")
        .Unprotect
        For i = 1 To 30
            .OptionButtons(i).Value = False
        Next i
        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```