# Form Option Button Reset Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a simple macro I could activate with a form control button that would clear all of the form control option buttons on my sheet.

I have lists of options for industrial part specifications, of which only one may be selected per section. However, once one is selected, the form control option button stays filled in. I previously circumvented this by using checkboxes, where if you click the box again it will remove the check mark. However once I learned that I was to create the form in such a way that only one option could be selected per section, (for ease of use in case a less computer minded person were to use it) it became clear that option buttons were the right way to go.

So I need a simple macro that I can activate with a button that will clear these option buttons all to blank, as if none were selected. I have looked and tried some strings of code, but none have worked so far. Perhaps I am missing something obvious or looking for the wrong thing, but I dont think I am.

I have checked the following pages and tried their code:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/689865-how-clear-all-checkboxes-option-buttons-list-boxes-form-3.html

[Re-setting all option buttons at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691864/re-setting-all-option-buttons-at-once)

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-buttons.html

I feel like this should be simple. A VBA macro code that will reset the FORM CONTROL Option Buttons to blank (which I believe is the false state?). No need to worry about having specific ranges to clear; one button to reset the sheet will do perfectly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Answer (score 1):

Cycle through the Shapes collection:

```
Sub Reset()
    For Each vCtrl In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        vCtrl.DrawingObject.Value = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: just tried your code under my module in VBA. Am I to use this there or under "Sheet1 (Sheet1)"?

In my attempt with it under Module, in Module1, I am getting an error on the line "Unload UserForm", which states: "UserForm=Empty"

To be clear, the option buttons are not in VBA UserForm, they are directly on the sheet, with the cells.

Comment: unfortunately, this updated code give me "run time error '438': Object doesnt support this property or method" on the line "vCtrl.DrawingObject.Value = False"

Comment: Do you have other objects on the sheet? It's hard to tell what's happening without seeing the actual workbook :(

Comment: The sheet is just lots of merged boxes with text and shading. It has 6 Drop down lists that use data validation, some of them conditional. Other than that there are groups of buttons (the buttons that need clearing) that are on the sheet, grouped by group boxes that are hidden with a vba code.